# Python: Can I have a string as a key and a function as value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

In other words, is this giving me errors purely because it's impossible to actually do or am I just writing it wrong:

```
class someClass:

    self.myString = "Hello"
    self.myMap =  {
    'someString' : self.functionInClass
    }
```

So if functionInClass takes an argument, I want to call it like so from anywhere inside the class:

```
self.myMap[self.myString](theArgument)
```

This just yields:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It appears `self` is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that, since methods (or bound methods) are just objects themselves.

In your code you forgot your function. I think you wanted to write somthing like this:

```
class someClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myString = "Hello"
        self.myMap =  {
            'someString' : self.functionInClass
        }

    def functionInClass(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly valid.

```
>>> def f():
...     print "test"
...
>>> d = {'df':f}
>>> d['df']()
test
>>>
```

This test code does not use a class, but same thing can be done with a class too. The error shows that `self` is not defined, it has nothing to do with functions in dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing impossible about what you're trying to do:

```
class Test(object):

  def func1(self, arg):
    print 'func1, arg=%s' % arg

  def func2(self, arg, **kwargs):
    print 'func2, arg=%s, kwargs=%s' % (arg, kwargs)

  funcmap = {'func1': func1, 'func2': func2}

  def invoke(self, fname, *args, **kwargs):
    Test.funcmap[fname](self, *args, **kwargs)

test = Test()
test.invoke('func1', 0)
test.invoke('func2', 42, kw=12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. Probably you just forgot something.
This works pretty well for me:

```
class someClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.myString = "someString"
        self.myMap =  {
            'someString' : self.functionInClass
        }   

    def functionInClass(self, argument):
        print argument

    def someMethod(self):
        self.myMap[self.myString]("argument")

cl = someClass()

cl.someMethod()
cl.myMap[cl.myString]("argument")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish for `myMap` to be a class attribute, make the dict values the string-name for the methods and use [getattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) to retrieve the actual method:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    myMap =  {
        'someString' : 'methodInClass'
        }
    def methodInClass(self,argument):
        pass

x = SomeClass()
getattr(x,x.myMap['someString'])('argument')
```